# Splitting Column data into unknown number of columns

Tags: r, regex, string, split

I have a very messy name column, names could look like the names below

```
names<-c("Mr John Jo Mcbride","Jim Bucket", "Farshad Jimbo Letrick")
```

The output could be any number of columns, separating into columns from spaces. So above the first name would need four columns, second 2 columns, third would be 3 columns.

I don't care about the order, I just want the data broken into how many ever columns each row needs based on the space separator.

Answer (score 3):

You may use `stringr` package , It has some of great functions for string manipulation,Use "str_split_fixed" to split the column basis your delimiter.

1) Calculate the number of words in your entire name, save it in a variable called len.
2) Use "str_split_fixed" to split it into the maximum value of len.
3) Rename your column as per your convenience.

```
data <- data.frame(names =c("Mr John Jo Mcbride","Jim Bucket", "Farshad Jimbo Letrick"),stringsAsFactors = F)
len <- sapply(gregexpr("\\W+", data$name), length) + 1
data$len <- len
library(stringr)
df_new <- data.frame(cbind(data,str_split_fixed(data$name, " ", max(len))))
names(df_new) <- c("names","length",paste0("name",1:max(len)))
df_new
```

**Answer:**

```
df_new
                  names length   name1  name2   name3   name4
1    Mr John Jo Mcbride      4      Mr   John      Jo Mcbride
2            Jim Bucket      2     Jim Bucket                
3 Farshad Jimbo Letrick      3 Farshad  Jimbo Letrick        
>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
names<-c("Mr John Jo Mcbride","Jim Bucket", "Farshad Jimbo Letrick")

strsplit(names,split = '\\s')
```